# Is there any way to get notified when my Chrome extension is beeing updated / uninstalled?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there some way to get notified, like an event, when an extension is beeing updated / uninstalled?

Comment: You can upvote and accept answers. See the [FAQ] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled) event you can listen to that fires when the extension is installed or updated.

There is no way of knowing if your extension is going to be uninstalled as of now, will probably never be one and as [@sowbug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344467/sowbug) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459822/is-there-any-way-to-get-notified-when-my-chrome-extension-is-beeing-updated-un/15459839?noredirect=1#comment21920023_15459839), shouldn't be one. They can't make events for all these situations (`onSubmergedInWater`, `onCrushed`), so it's better to encourage developers to keep the app or extension in a killable state at all times (see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lm-Vnx58UYo) to get an idea of what I'm talking about).

Quoting from their [FAQ page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq.html#faq-lifecycle-events):

> **Can extensions be notified when they are installed/uninstalled?**
>
> You can listen to the runtime.onInstalled event to be notified when
>   your extension is installed or updated, or when Chrome itself is
>   updated. There is no corresponding event for when your extension is
>   uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I need to get notified _before_ the extension is updated, because Google closes all tabs associated with an extension before updating / uninstalling it and in the case of [my extension](https://github.com/343max/TabHibernation) it might contain user data that is otherwise lost.

Comment: @343max No idea about that. Why can't you store the info some place? Also, love your extension. Way easier than opening up Task Manager everytime and finding and killing tabs there.

Comment: @343max Thanks for the accept BTW. You can also upvote my answer. About your particular question, could you provide more detail about what data exactly are you going to lose?

Comment: I like it too, but you will lose all your hibernated tabs on every update of the extension. That is not exactable. I don't want the hassle of collecting / storing / replacing all the tabs every time, because it's complicated and error prone. I'm thinking about using data-URIs instead of internal links but that's bäh.

Comment: @343max Why don't you restore the tabs, store the tab IDs and hibernate them again when your extension is installed. Since there's no event like that, modify your extension to check.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you mean. When should I restore the tabs? For now I fixed it with data-URIs. Chrome will not close data URIs when updating or installing the extension, so it should be much safer.

Comment: @343max Since you said the event was triggered before the actual update, I suggested restoring the tabs then. But it seems you have found your solutions.

Comment: "... and will probably never be one." Upvote in particular for this. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lm-Vnx58UYo. We can't make events for all these situations (onSubmergedInWater, onCrushed) so it's better to encourage developers to keep the app/extension in a killable state at all times.